# Annotation to log the execution time of each test case in Junit5

Tags: time, execution, junit5

I have a requirement to log the execution time for each test case. I don't want to use a custom implementation. I want to know whether there is an annotation available for this in junit5
Btw, I know about `Stopwatch` or Junit4 `@Timeout`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After a look through into junit5 documentation, I found this sample
[TimeExtension](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions-lifecycle-callbacks-timing-extension)

This snippet is from their docs:

```
@ExtendWith(TimingExtension.class)
class TimingExtensionTests {

  @Test
  void sleep20ms() throws Exception {
     Thread.sleep(20);
  }

  @Test
  void sleep50ms() throws Exception {
    Thread.sleep(50);
  }

}
```

EDIT: [Source code for TimingExtension](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/blob/master/documentation/src/test/java/example/timing/TimingExtension.java)

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a [`BenchmarkExtension`](https://github.com/CodeFX-org/demo-junit-5/blob/master/src/main/java/org/codefx/demo/junit5/BenchmarkExtension.java) that you can apply with [`@Benchmark`](https://github.com/CodeFX-org/demo-junit-5/blob/master/src/main/java/org/codefx/demo/junit5/Benchmark.java). You can use it as follows:

```
@Benchmark
class BenchmarkTest {

    @Test
    void notBenchmarked() {
        assertTrue(true);
    }

    @Test
    @Benchmark
    void benchmarked() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(100);
        assertTrue(true);
    }

}
```

When applied to the class you will get a single message with the total run time of all the tests methods in that class. When applied to a single test method, you will get a message for that test only.

I hope it will eventually find its way into [JUnit Pioneer](http://junit-pioneer.org).

Comment: When you screw up your own project's name...  Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing special that needs to be done to get the execution time for a test case in JUnit 5 - Jupiter.

The time is right there in the XML report.

On the 'testCase' element, there is a property 'time', which gives the time for execution of the test case. Below is an example. The times are in seconds

```
<testcase name="checkZKConnectivityWithAuth" 
          classname="test.zk.ZookeeperConnectionProviderTests" 
          time="7.177"/>

<testcase name="checkConfigRetrieval" 
          classname="test.zk.ZookeeperConnectionProviderTests" 
          time="0.213"/>

<testcase name="checkConfigInsertion" 
          classname="test.zk.ZookeeperConnectionProviderTests" 
          time="0.255"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Junit5 also has a [@Timout](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-declarative-timeouts) annotation.

There is also an `assertTimeout` and `assertTimeoutPreemptively` (see [documentation](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-assertions)).

Finally, the JUnit 4 Stopwatch functionality is not available in JUnit 5. Use `TimeExtension` as already mentioned. However this extension is **not** (yet?) part of the distribution (see [issue 343](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/343)).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Sonarqube, you can find time duration of each test and total of all test sorted by time

[test time sorted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28jwC.png)

[all test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLDMg.png)